# How to delete old data in supabase

Tags: supabase, netlify-function

I have a supabase app and my database is filled with old data and i want to delete it using a scheduled netlify function how can i implement this? I want it to delete data that is more than a month old, the scheduled function will run daily, and the delete will be to a specific table named Data

Comment: What is old data? E.g a day old?  A month / year? 

How often do you want to run this? Why not use pg_cron and run this from Supabase directly?  Is this for a specific table or all of them?

Comment: I didn't know that there was such thing as pg_cron i will use it thanks